# Recyclerview watchlist keeping the Viewholder in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` in a fragment that lists movies based on genre and each movie has an "add to watchlist" button and then this movie object gets stored in the `Arraylist` of my `WatchlistAdapter` when the button is clicked, so to be saved in another `RecyclerView`, that is in another fragment, the watchlist fragment. Each movie item that is saved in the watchlist; is a relative layout that contains its title. All is set and done, but the problem persists when I shut down my device or emulator, shutting down clears the watchlist. I want a way to save the watchlist in the user's device.

Comment: i think you should read android notepad tutorial, ask uncle google for it

Comment: lol uncle google knows all, thx

Comment: its not me, its uncle google, you should thx

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html (for bystanders who can't or won't google)

Comment: where would we be without google, thanks guys

Comment: Go through: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-android-tutorial-writing-firebase-data/